# Script seems to lock mysql server

Tags: php, mysqli, sleep

Below is a simple example program to show the problem I am having.  I am searching the database for new jobs executing them then going to sleep until there are new jobs.  I am doing it this way because they must be run 1 at a time.  However when I execute the script the server will not let any scripts run that access the database.  Why is the database locked?

```
ignore_user_abort(true);//if caller closes the connection (if initiating with cURL from another PHP, this allows you to end the calling PHP script without ending this one)
//set_time_limit(0);    //run forever

//start up
session_start();
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", __file__.".log");
require_once("includes/loginMaster.php");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATA);
if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);


//setup statement for getting tasks
$query='SELECT `id`,`uid`,`kid`,`type`,`value`,`time` FROM `data_que` WHERE `executed` IS NULL ORDER BY `time` ASC, `id` ASC LIMIT 1';
$stmtNext = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmtNext->bind_result($id,$uid,$kid,$type,$value,$time);

//get packets
while(true) {
    $stmtNext->execute();$stmtNext->store_result();
    while ($stmtNext->fetch()) {
        /*
            should do somthing here but removed for simplicity

        */



        //reexecute job
        $stmtNext->execute();$stmtNext->store_result();
        usleep(100);
    }
    sleep(5);
    echo "slept";
}
```

Comment: Why do you call sleep?

Comment: if I didn't sleep the script would eat a lot of resources while it waits.

Comment: i am using innodb.  though I don't believe I am leaving it ever in a locked state

Comment: Why the `session_start()` ? Does the other script used the same session ?

Comment: @frz3993 thanks.  please submit that as an answer.  The session_start is cut and paste error from initialising other scripts.  this one being cronjob does not need it is the session hanging it not the database

Comment: The database isn't locked. Everything works except **your** browser. This happens because you're using Apache as your web server. It does something called http pipelining. It's an optimization step, which is archaic in this time and age, and it manifests in such a way that if you open a few tabs in your browser, they won't load the site until the first tab is finished loading. Also, this code can be improved, you can probably use MySQL's event scheduler to perform the entire work at MySQL side. However, without much info - there's no way to suggest an alternative. Also, `sleep` eats resources.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse, I don't even know why that happened. I was just assuming it has something to do with session file locking. That only happens with browsers. LOL

Comment: @frz3993 well you were correct and you may as well get credit for the answer.